# Entropy used to calculate energy?

Tags: energy, entropy

I'm currently reading an online article, and below is a quote from that article:

> The thermodynamic entropy to change $n$ memory cells within $m$ states is $ΔS=k_B\ln(m^n)$, where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant. From the second law of thermodynamics, $ΔS=\dfrac{ΔQ}{T}$, where $ΔQ$ is the energy spent and $T$ is the temperature. So the energy required to write information into one binary memory bit is $E_{bit}= k_BT \ln2$.

But from what I've learned, $Q$ is heat transfer, not 'energy spent'. Why is it possible to use those 2 interchangeably, if it's possible?

Comment: Can you please post a link to the article so we can see the context in which they are using these relations.